# How To Open New Tab In Custom WKWebView Implementation

Tags: swiftui, webkit

I have a custom webview implementation that looks like this:

```
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavigationState
    @Binding var proxy: GeometryProxy
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView  {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        guard let webView = navigationState.selectedWebView else {
            return
        }
        if webView != uiView.subviews.first {
            uiView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
            
            webView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: proxy.size)
            uiView.addSubview(webView)
            
            // Inject JavaScript to capture long-press on a specific button
            let script = """
                document.querySelector('#specificButtonId').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.buttonLongPress.postMessage(null);
                });
                """
            let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
            webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        }
    }
}

class NavigationState : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentURL : URL?
    @Published var webViews : [WKWebView] = []
    @Published var selectedWebView : WKWebView?
    
    var buttonLongPressPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var nextURL: URL?
    
    @discardableResult func createNewWebView(withRequest request: URLRequest) -> WKWebView {
        let wv = WKWebView()
        wv.navigationDelegate = self
        webViews.append(wv)
        selectedWebView = wv
        wv.load(request)
        return wv
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        currentURL = webView.url
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
            
            nextURL = url
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
    
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "buttonLongPress" {
            print("Presssed")
            buttonLongPressPublisher.send()
        }
    }
    
}

struct WebViewWrapper: View {
    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavigationState
    let proxy: GeometryProxy
    let isSideMenuAttached: Bool
    @Binding var width: Int
    @Binding var contextMenuVisible: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        WebView(navigationState: navigationState, proxy: .constant(proxy))
            .frame(width: isSideMenuAttached ? proxy.size.width : proxy.size.width - CGFloat(width))
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .onReceive(navigationState.buttonLongPressPublisher) { _ in
                if let webView = navigationState.selectedWebView {
                    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.URL") { result, _ in
                        if let urlString = result as? String, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                            // Perform the desired action, e.g., print the URL
                            print("Long-pressed URL: \(url)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

For now, I want just to print out the next URL that the view would be going to. For example, if I go to apple.com, and on the top left there is the apple logo I would want the user to press and hold there and see an option to print out the next URL. Currently, if I do that, I see 4 options:

- Open Link (to Safari not a new tab in my app)
- Add to reading list
- copy link
- share

What I would want is to remove the open link option and add my own. I am pretty stuck with this, so any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use makeUIView to make the webview, instead of creating them in your navigation state. State should just store things like current URL, URL history, you know state.

makeUIView() should be creating the webview and returning that instead of an empty UIView, and updateView is called whenever any state updates. You use updateView to load new URLs, etc.

You need to make a Coordinator class within your WebView, and have that coordinator conform to the WKWebView's delegates. (I believe in your case the navigation delegate). In your makeUIView(), assign the coordinator to be the delegate. e.g. `webview.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator`

For example:

```swift
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
…
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView  {
        let webView = WKWebView…
        …
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        guard let webView = uiView as? WKWebView else { return }
        // update the webView based on navigation state
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator: WKNavigationDelegate {
        // implement navigation delegate methods here
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, so basically ditch the navigationState altogether? But how would this help with the `open in new tab` feature?

Comment: @anish1 in your Coordinator, where you handle the URL navigation delegate methods, you would intercept the URL and trigger your app to open a new tab in your app window with a new WKWebView. Possibly through a notification. WKWebView won't open new tabs for you automatically, nor would adding subviews to a UIView - that would just stack them on top of each other. You would need to manage your tabs yourself. The navigationState might be a good place for that, but I don't know how the rest of your app is architected so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I understood what you did here, and I implemented it in. Sorry for the late reply